# Unusual static_cast syntax

Tags: c++, casting

I managed to track a bug down to the following expression:

```
foo(static_cast<T>(a, b)); // Executes specialisation 1
```

The closing bracket was in the wrong place.  The correct statement should have been:

```
foo(static_cast<T>(a), b); // Executes specialisation 2
```

I've never seen static_cast used with the form (a,b), or seen it described anywhere.  What does it mean?  The former statement returned b.

Comment: It's just a bug, not a special case of a static_cast. It's the comma operator, doing its thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`static_cast` is not a function, it's a keyword, so the comma in `a, b` is not an argument separator; it is the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). It evaluates `a` but throws away the result. The expression evaluates to `b`.

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with `static_cast`, but "makes use" of the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Its result is its right hand side, so

```
foo(static_cast<T>(a, b));
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(static_cast<T>(b));
```

unless `a` has other effects (which would then be executed and have their result discarded). With the right compiler settings, you will be warned about such things: [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f40af444b46b7463)

Comment: Why is ""makes use"" in quotation marks like you're being ironic or hiding a secret meaning?

Comment: @KerrekSB "Makes use" in the sense "No one actually intended to use this", i.e. no one *actually* makes use of it, they just happened to invoke it on accident.

Answer (score 0):

`,` is comma operator, so `a, b` is just `b`